# How to check if days between two dates are weekdays?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have form where user take two dates from calendar. I want to check if days between two dates that user selected are in from friday to monday (include).

I found script that count weekdays (days that are include satuday and sunday):

```
function calcBusinessDays (dDate1, dDate2) {
    var iWeeks, iDateDiff, iAdjust = 0;

    if (dDate2 < dDate1) return 0;

    var iWeekday1 = dDate1.getDay();
    var iWeekday2 = dDate2.getDay();

    iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday1; // change Sunday from 0 to 7
    iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday2;

    if ((iWeekday1 > 5) && (iWeekday2 > 5)) iAdjust = 1; // adjustment if both days on weekend

    iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday1; // only count weekdays
    iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday2;

    // calculate differnece in weeks (1000mS * 60sec * 60min * 24hrs * 7 days = 604800000)
    iWeeks = Math.floor((dDate2.getTime() - dDate1.getTime()) / 604800000)

    if (iWeekday1 <= iWeekday2) {
        iDateDiff = (iWeeks * 5) + (iWeekday2 - iWeekday1)
    } else {
        iDateDiff = ((iWeeks + 1) * 5) - (iWeekday1 - iWeekday2)
    }

    iDateDiff -= iAdjust // take into account both days on weekend

    return (iDateDiff + 1); // add 1 because dates are inclusive
}
```

how to modify it to include friday and monday?

Comment: You are asking how to get the number of days between two dates and not business days?

Comment: I know this may be a language barrier issue, but can you be a bit more specific. I really don't understand exactly want your "expected" result is?

Answer (score 2):

Just put this together real quick but it should work.
I had trouble understanding your sample code. Just thought this might work a little better.

```
var calcBusinessDays = function (dDate1, dDate2) {
    //We are working with time stamps
    var from = dDate1.getTime()
    ,   to = dDate2.getTime()
    ,   tempDate = new Date()
    ,   count = 0;

    //loop through each day between the dates 86400000 = 1 day
    for(var _from = from; _from < to; _from += 86400000){
        //set the day
        tempDate.setTime(_from);
        //If it is a weekend add 1 to count
        if ((tempDate.getDay() <= 1) || (tempDate.getDay() >= 5)) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    //return count =)
    return count;
}
```

This will add 1 for Friday, Saturday, Sunday and Monday.
The only line that would need to be changed if you wanted other days would be the if statement nested in the for loop.